# What should I consider when using a sewage ejector pump?

Tags: plumbing

What are some of the things that you need to consider if you have a sewage ejector pump regarding maintenance and prevention of abominable, excrable catastrophes?

From what I gather this thing is akin to a giant garbage disposal with a pump that mashes up sewage and pushes it up to a point where it's above, elevation-wise, the nearest sewer line. It's probably most commonly used in old basements that have been dug out.

Comment: not sure what a sewage ejection pump is?  any links?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From this article http://burnettplumbing.com/tenways/; Step #6 talks about a sewage ejector pump:

> **If you have a sewage ejector pump in your basement, plan for the fact that it will eventually fail.**
>   These pumps operate in a very harsh
>   environment (submersed in sewage) and
>   often fail after just a few years.
>   Failure of your pump could mean sewage
>   back-up in your basement. The risk of
>   a damaging back-up is especially high
>   if you have a water softener which
>   drains into the sewage ejector system.
>   If the softener regenerates while the
>   ejector pump is not functioning, you
>   could end up with up to 100 gallons of
>   sewage backing up through the floor
>   drain. All of this could happen at
>   night while you are asleep, that is
>   when most softeners regenerate.
>   Consider installing an alarm in your
>   sewage ejector tank. An alarm is
>   designed to buzz loudly in the event
>   of pump failure. Assuming you're home
>   when this occurs, you should have
>   ample time to shut-off your water
>   before the sewage reaches flood level.
>   Remember, alarms can fail too! It is
>   best to NOT store valuable items on
>   the basement floor if they could be
>   damaged by water or sewage flooding.